# HTTPClient: After successfully calling ASYNC GET for the second time, application continue but next method using the result, never gets called

Tags: c#, httpclient

I have two similar scenarios using HTTPClient. One is a post method, and one is a get.

The code to call the post is like this:

```
 GetHuntGroupRequest getHuntGroupRequest = new GetHuntGroupRequest();

                        getHuntGroupRequest.accountId = customer.AccountNumber.AccountId;
                        getHuntGroupRequest.divisionId = customer.AccountNumber.DivisionId.Split('.')[0];

                        var responseFttp = FttpClient.SendDataToFTTPService<GetHuntGroupFeatureResponse>("BPS/GetHuntGroup", getHuntGroupRequest, FTTP_APIMethodVerb.POST); //This is calling the HTTPClient POST.

                        customer = FttpDeserailizer.HuntGroupFeatureDeserailizer(responseFttp.Result, customer);
```

The call "HuntGroupFeatureDeserailizer" runs sucessfully after the result from SendDataToFTTPService is done.

However then, I make the same logic, but instead, using a GET method. The code is like this:

```
 var responseFttp = FttpClient.GetDataFromFTTPService<GetAutoAttendantResponse>($"BPS/AutoAttendant/accountNumber/{customer.AccountNumber.AccountId}/siteCode/{customer.AccountNumber.DivisionId.Split('.')[0]}"); //This calls the HTTPClient GET.

                        customer = FttpDeserailizer.AutoAttendantFeatureDeserailizer(responseFttp.Result, customer);
```

And here lies the problem. The application continue it's execution after "GetDataFromFTTPService" call, and even after I have the result, the call "AutoAttendantFeatureDeserailizer" never get's called.

This is the code inside the method of both, POST and GET async methods:

```
public static async Task<T> SendDataToFTTPService<T>(string methodHostAndName, object Request, FTTP_APIMethodVerb HTTPVerb)
    { 

        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | (SecurityProtocolType)192 | (SecurityProtocolType)768 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072 | (SecurityProtocolType)12288;

        var jsonRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Request);
        var data = new StringContent(jsonRequest, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var client = new HttpClient();

        //var authToken = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{bpsUserName}:{bpsPassword}");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BPSCredentials"].ToString());

        HttpResponseMessage response;

        if (HTTPVerb == FTTP_APIMethodVerb.POST)
            response = await client.PostAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BPSHostUrlForFTTP"].ToString() + methodHostAndName, data).ConfigureAwait(false);
        
        else
            response = await client.PutAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BPSHostUrlForFTTP"].ToString() + methodHostAndName, data).ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK && methodHostAndName == "EWS/CheckFiber")
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>("{\"hasFiber\":true}");
        else if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);            
        else
            throw new Exception("There was an error communicating to the service");


    }

public static async Task<T> GetDataFromFTTPService<T>(string methodHostAndStringRequest)
    {

        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | (SecurityProtocolType)192 | (SecurityProtocolType)768 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072 | (SecurityProtocolType)12288;


        var client = new HttpClient();

        //var authToken = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{bpsUserName}:{bpsPassword}");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BPSCredentials"].ToString());

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BPSHostUrlForFTTP"].ToString() + methodHostAndStringRequest).ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
        else
            throw new Exception("There was an error communicating to the service");


    }
```

As you can see, both scenarios are similar, but when calling the POST method, it successfully runs the next method after results are complete, but in the second scenario, the method after the GET call gets ignored.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: For debugging purposes, could you please put something like `var result = responseFttp.Result;` in an own line and perhaps wrap that in a try-catch block (with a breakpoint in the catch block). Then you can probably see whether accessing the result throws an exception or if not whether the result contains what you expect.

Comment: Hello @HeroWanders. I did put var result = responseFttp.Result; after the call but the execution never arrives to that line either. After I receive successful ok status from the server, it stays for a while in return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result); and then it get's out of the method.

Comment: Then try writing `var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` to an own line and wrap it again with a try-catch block. Put a breakpoint in its catch block or log a potential exception there.

Comment: @HeroWanders I did, and I was able to access the result. I then tried to deserailize under try and catch block and there is the problem. The type used to deserailize was wrong, and return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result); fails silently. Thank you man.

Comment: Also dont call `Result`... ever, `await` it